# Как сделать поиск по нескольким полям в Qt

Tags: qt

У меня есть таблица, я сделала поиск по имени используя QLineEdit, как сделать, чтобы поиск выполнялся и по фамилии, по баллу, и по номеру группы?
Данный кусочек отвечает за поиск по имени, находится в cpp файле:

```
void MainWindow::on_SearchLineEdit_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    model->setFilter(QString("firstname LIKE '%%1%'").arg(arg1));
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно с помощью регулярных выражений и QRegExp

Comment: Можете подробнее объяснить? Я читала, но не могу понять, как это сделать

Comment: Неправильно подсказал. Если это работа с БД, то нужно делать фильтр в формате SQL-запроса. Я бы сделал несколько QLineEdit для каждого параметра, и при изменении значения хоть в одном, собираете значения из каждого и упаковываете в строку в виде model->setFilter(QString("NAME=%1 AND SURNAME = %2").arg(lineEditName->text()).arg(lineEditSurname->text()));

Comment: Несколько QLineEdit для каждого параметра? Мне нужно добавить ещё строку?
я так поняла, что это строка должна быть вместо моей : model->setFilter(QString("NAME=%1 AND SURNAME = %2").arg(lineEditName->text()).arg(lineEditSurname->text()));

Comment: Да. QLineEdit для имени и QLineEdit для фамилии и тд...